# No me funciona el archivo css vinculado a mi html

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando conectar mi archivo html a css pero a la hora de hacer cambios en el css no se muestran en el html.

Cabe recalcar que también lo hice de esta forma:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">`

y aún así no me funciona.

También probé crear una carpeta aparte y poner el archivo css dentro de la misma, luego indiqué la carpeta y el archivo css dentro de la carpeta y escribirlo en href y nada, de igual forma probé quitando el punto antes del / y tampoco nada.

Archivo HTML vinculado con CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es-CO"> 

<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./images/html5.png"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"> 

    <title>Mi primera web</title> 

</head>
```

Comment: / dejale solo el style.css
espero que sea solo eso

Comment: Hola Eduardo, si el archivo **css** está en la misma carpeta que el **html** usa esta referencia: **<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">**.

Comment: La primera vez que pones el nombre del archivo lo nombras como **estilos.css**, la segundavez lo nombras como **styles.css**. Asegurate de que te estás refiriendo al archivo que realmente existe. El formato de enlace parece correcto, faltaría ver tu directorio de carpetas a ver donde estás almacenando los archivos para asegurarse de la ruta correcta entre tu html y la hoja de estilos. Y, además, actualiza la pagina al realizar algun cambio en la hoja de estilos.

Comment: Repliqué tu código y no veo error alguno.  Usé `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">`

Comment: Usar `href="./styles.css"` o `href="styles.css"` no es la causa del problema porque son funcionalmente equivalentes.